# Passing concrete instance to closure that expects a protocol parameter

Tags: ios, swift, macos, types, alamofire

In my app, I have a function to call a specific API endpoint of mine, and that function accepts a closure as a completion handler. That closure accepts a `Result` of my custom `Decodable` type (`Category`) in the `success` case, and an `Error` in the `failure` case. Altogether, its method signature looks like this:

```
static func getAllRestaurantCategories(completion: @escaping (Result<[Category], Error>) -> Void) -> Void
```

This function calls out to Alamofire to determine the languages that the server supports, and then get the list of all possible restaurant categories. It's implemented like this:

```
static func getAllRestaurantCategories(completion: @escaping (Result<[Category], Error>) -> Void) -> Void{
    API.localizedRequest(API.categories) { (request: DataRequest) in
        request.responseDecodable(of: [Category].self) { (response: DataResponse<[Category], AFError>) in
            completion(response.result)
        }
    }
}
```

However, on the line with `completion(response.result)`, I get a compiler error that says `Cannot convert value of type 'Result<[Category], AFError>' to expected argument type 'Result<[Category], Error>'`. This error goes away if I change the closure my method accepts to accept an `AFError` in the `failure` case, like this:

```
static func getAllRestaurantCategories(completion: @escaping (Result<[Category], AFError>) -> Void) -> Void{
    API.localizedRequest(API.categories) { (request: DataRequest) in
        request.responseDecodable(of: [Category].self) { (response: DataResponse<[Category], AFError>) in
            completion(response.result)
        }
    }
}
```

Alamofire's `AFError` conforms to `Error`, so it seems to me that this should work just fine. I know I can parse Alamofire's `Result` myself and generate my own to pass to my completion handler, but I'd rather not write all that extra custom code if I don't have to. How can I get the type system to understand that this should be ok?

Comment: I assume the compiler is complaining about swift `Result` type vs  Alamofire `Result` type and not the error type

Comment: I thought that at first, but when I dug deeper, I found that Alamofire's `Result` is, in fact, `Swift.Result`. If I change the closure my method accepts to accept `AFError` as the `failure` case of the `Result` it's given, the compiler is perfectly happy. This makes me think that it doesn't get that `AFError` conforms to `Error`, for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, in (at least the current version of) Swift, if `Sub` is a subtype of `Base`, that doesn't mean that `Container<Sub>` is a subtype of `Container<Base>`.

In fact, `Container<Sub>` and `Container<Base>` are unrelated types.

So, while we can do the following:

```
protocol Car {}
struct Toyota: Car {}

let a: Car = Toyota()
```

but we can't generally (with notable exception of Swift's standard library collection types) do this:

```
struct Container<T> {}

let c: Container<Car> = Container<Toyota>() // ERROR
```

It is said that `Container<Car>` and `Container<Toyota>` are not covariant

---

`Result` has a `mapError` function that should make it fairly painless:

```
completion(response.result.mapError { $0 as Error } )
```